# Cannot refer to non-final variable and Timer

Tags: java, timer, anonymous-class

I'm trying to write a static class which could change a background of control, which will be passed to the parameter. So I achieved this:

```
public static void wrong(final Component component) {

        component.setBackground(Color.RED);
        Timer   timer = new Timer(2, wrongAction);

        wrongAction = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int green = component.getBackground().getGreen();
                int blue = component.getBackground().getBlue();
                component.setBackground(new Color(255, green + 1, blue + 1));
                if (component.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        };

        timer.start();

    }
```

And I've got a error:

```
Cannot refer to a non-final variable timer inside an inner class defined in a different method
```

of course, we can change timer to final, but method stops working after we do that.
I tried to google it and to find answer in other stackoverflow topics, but nothing helped me.

Thanks a lot to everybody in advance!

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). BTW - do you have a question?  What is it?

Comment: In what way does the method stop working after you make timer final?

Comment: Just change to "final Timer timer = " ?? It works fine for me.

Comment: Your '==' condition looks very suspicious, I would use 'equals()' instead. Making Timer t final should solve your problem. From what we see there, I don't see issues if you change that.

Comment: "we can change timer to final, but method stops working after we do that" ...what happens exactly?  What if you start() timer earlier?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Why, it's an `int`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#WHITE

Comment: @DaveNewton No, to me it is an Object (since he does new Color(...)). In Swing, Color's are objects

Comment: @GuillaumePolet Whoops, for some reason I was thinking this was an Android question--I have no idea why I thought that, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you use a different wrongAction reference.

```
public static void wrong(final Component component) {

    component.setBackground(Color.RED);
    Timer   timer = new Timer(2, wrongAction);// <-- Here wrongAction is not the one you
                                              // define on the next line

    wrongAction = new ActionListener() { // <-- This is a new ActionListener but Timer
                                         // has no knowledge about it.
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int green = component.getBackground().getGreen();
            int blue = component.getBackground().getBlue();
            component.setBackground(new Color(255, green + 1, blue + 1));
            if (component.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();

}
```

The following code will work immediately (but I don't find that very clean, would be better to encapsulate all this in an dedicated object, so that Timer can be a variable of the class and the listener could refer to it):

```
public static void wrong(final Component component) {
        class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
            private Timer timer;

            public void setTimer(Timer timer) {
                this.timer = timer;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int green = component.getBackground().getGreen();
                int blue = component.getBackground().getBlue();
                component.setBackground(new Color(255, green + 1, blue + 1));
                if (component.getBackground().equals(Color.WHITE)) {
                    if (timer == null) {
                        System.err.println("This sucks, I got no timer");
                    } else {
                        timer.stop();
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        MyActionListener wrongAction = new MyActionListener();
        component.setBackground(Color.RED);
        Timer timer = new Timer(2, wrongAction);
        wrongAction.setTimer(timer);


        timer.start();

    }
```

Comment: that's what i really wanted! Thank you so much!

Comment: I wish this had been around when I was doing the same thing. Had to figure it out on my own after much bumbling around :D

Answer (score 1):

you seem to passing wrongAction to timer constructor and then actually initializing it!!!

shouldn't the code

```
wrongAction = new ActionListener() {...
        };
```

be above

```
Timer   timer = new Timer(2, wrongAction);
```

???

Ofcourse, you need Timer timer =null; at the top

EDITED:
How about you remove the wrongAction completely and keep it simple like this-

```
final Timer   timer = new Timer(2, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                int green = component.getBackground().getGreen();
                int blue = component.getBackground().getBlue();
                component.setBackground(new Color(255, green + 1, blue + 1));
                if (component.getBackground() == Color.WHITE) {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
```

;

Comment: This does not work, you still can't refer to timer from within the ActionListener

Comment: well just make it final in that case...the point i am trying to make is "wrongAction" need to be intialized earlier or completely removed

Comment: That won't work either. Compiler will complain that timer may have not been initialized yet.

Comment: ohh!! just wondering how? final Timer timer = new Timer(2, new ActionListner(){...});      ....I think this code should initialized! shouldn't it?

Comment: No, first you create ActionListener, which will require a reference to timer, since one of the method of ActionListener uses a reference to the final variable timer, then Timer is created.

Comment: you are right! in case of timer.stop(), timer will not yet be intialized.

Answer (score 0):

wrongAction is an inner class and Java requires the local variables define outside needs to be final in order for it to be used in the inner class:

```
final Timer   timer = new Timer(2, wrongAction);

wrongAction = new ActionListener() {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass a null in the constructor and then add an `ActionListener`

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(2,null);

timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
//...
});
timer.start();
```